CNN model for text classification summary showing no output shape and unbuilt params
I am attempting to create a CNN model for text classification based on tweet data with the ELMo embedding. Once the model is built before compiling I am issuing a model summary but the model summary is showing 0 params, 0 trainable params and 0 un-trainable params. I'm thinking the issue could be in the input shape or the lack of padding but unsure of how to proceed. Here's the code I have implemented.
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x = seeker_df[['tweet']]
y = seeker_df['BinaryNumTarget']

#splitting into validation and test - 85% of dataset if train and validation, 15% for test
x_train_val, x_test, y_train_val, y_test = train_test_split(x,
                                                            y, 
                                                            test_size =0.15,
                                                            stratify = y, # sampling used to ensure class distribution
                                                            random_state = 42)

#splitting into train and val - 70% for training, 15% for validation
x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(x_train_val, 
                                                  y_train_val, 
                                                  test_size =0.1765,
                                                  stratify = y_train_val, 
                                                  random_state=42)
#package installation 
from keras.models import Sequential 
from keras.layers import Conv1D, GlobalMaxPooling1D, Dense
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

#setting up parameters
no_of_filters = 250
kernel_size = 3
hidden_dims = 250
batch_size = 32
epochs = 2
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor ='val_loss', patience = 10)

#obtaining elmo emmbedding
elmo = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2", 
                      trainable=True,
                      name = 'elmo_embedding',
                      input_shape=[],
                     dtype=(tf.string))
embedding = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(elmo)

model = Sequential()

model.add(embedding)

model.add(Conv1D(no_of_filters, kernel_size, activation ='relu'))

model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())

model.add(Dense(hidden_dims, activation = 'relu'))

model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

model.summary()


This is the model summary I am currently obtaining. Any help would be appreciated. I know the epochs and the early stopping do not currently make sense, but running low epochs to begin with to test.
Model: "sequential_5"
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ Layer (type)                         ┃ Output Shape                ┃         Param # ┃
┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│ lambda_3 (Lambda)                    │ ?                           │     0 (unbuilt) │
├──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ conv1d_3 (Conv1D)                    │ ?                           │     0 (unbuilt) │
├──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ global_max_pooling1d_3               │ ?                           │               0 │
│ (GlobalMaxPooling1D)                 │                             │                 │
├──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ dense_6 (Dense)                      │ ?                           │     0 (unbuilt) │
├──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ dense_7 (Dense)                      │ ?                           │     0 (unbuilt) │
└──────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────┴─────────────────┘
 Total params: 0 (0.00 B)
 Trainable params: 0 (0.00 B)
 Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 B)


I've made some changes to your code. To keep the pretrained ELMo model fixed,
I've set its trainable parameter to False. I've also used tf.keras to add
layers to the Sequential model and reshaped the ELMo output to a 3D format,
which is compatible with Conv1D layers. These changes have made the code
operational. For a detailed look at the updated code, please refer to the
gist.

Thank you for this! The issues you've highlighted have fixed it so the model is working fro the summary but when I do a model fit I am getting and attribute error.
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'outer_context'
Any thoughts on why this could be? Or what could cause this? Thank you

Please provide the code so that I can reproduce

Here's the full code, the error happens when I both do the tokenization steps and don't. code
